# What does "modern finvenkismo" look like?

Tags: culture

I understand that "finvenkismo" is the original, idealistic current within the Esperanto movement, dating back to Zamenhof. I'm wondering if and how this ideology has changed in the last 100 years. Are there any modern reading materials that would tell me how "finvenkismo" looks like today?

Here are some of the questions I'm wondering about:

- What do finvenkistoj think about all the Esperanto-specific culture that appeared in the last 100 years? Does it affect the cultural neutrality of Esperanto?
- Do finvenkistoj still think that Esperanto as a universal second langauge would help eradicating wars and chauvinism, or do they rather concentrate on more down-to-earth advantages of the language, such as more regular pronunciation and grammar than in English?
- Are they for or against introducing Esperanto in places such as European Union bodies? Is it a problem that it would make the language less politically neutral?

Comment: I know it hasn't got much to do with your question, but a member came up with a very nice alternative definition of *La fina venko* at the latest SEF-meeting. We had been discussing earlier the same day how to respond to questions like "Is Esperanto to any use at all?". He said that to him, *La fina venko* simply means not having to to explain to people what the use of Esperanto is. I agree, the goal should be making Esperanto known and respected instead of making everybody speak it.

Comment: @AntoniaMontaro It is relevant to my question, I'm interested in how people interpret *la fina venko* today. Dankon!

Comment: Few Esperanto-speakers enthusiastically identify themselves with these sorts of labels. They allude to rather stale, storm-in-a-teacup political disputes involving small numbers of people. So, unfortunately you may have trouble finding *finvenkistoj* who can answer your questions in a genuinely representative way.

Answer (score 2):

You will get as many different answers to this question as there are Esperantists to answer it. Since the *fina venko* looks different to different people, each will have his own notion of what *finvenkismo* is. It hasn't changed so much as the various proportions of people who are in favor of various forms of it may have shifted in various directions over the years.

You have some good questions there, but they get muddied up when you try to tie them to *finvenkismo*.